# Analyzing slow mysql server

Tags: mysql, rds

I have noticed that my mysql instance on Amazon's RDS is running quite slow. When I run:

```
SELECT NOW()
```

From my local computer, it takes 0.2ms to run. When I run that same query on rds, it takes 35.1ms to run -- even running these multiple times to rule out caching it's about that value.

What are some things I can do or tools I can use to figure out why the rds server is running so slow?

Comment: How are you connecting to the two servers? I am willing to bet that you are connecting to your local instance through a socket file.

Comment: @e4c5 -- yes, that's correct. Would it be possible to connect to rds via a socket as well? Or what's the best that I can do?

Comment: Unfortunately no because it will be on a separate server. If this lag is an issue, your option is to get a bigger compute instance and put both web and db on the same machine. Then they can communicate via socket files.